# Entity Framework Code First - Is there a way to create a model diagram from POCO classes

Tags: entity-framework, model, poco, diagram

I'm really into the new Entity Framework code first features (currently at CTP5 at the moment). One thing which would be ace would be the ability to generate some kind of model diagram from the POCO classes that I build.

Does such a tool exist? Preferably I'm looking for an open source solution if possible.

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use built-in class diagram in Visual studio.

Comment: Ahh, yes I recall that you can do this. That should do the trick, I'll give it a shot. Cheers.

Comment: unable to build, please tell how to do??

Comment: @Praveen: Sorry it was typo. It should not be *build in* but *built-in*.

Comment: yes: but how to do it,iam unable to create.

Comment: @Praveen: Just add Class diagram and include your classes: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klOFiX_DmjE

Answer (score 3):

The MS ADO.NET guys have released a tool that's awesome for diagramming your EF Code-First context. There's more to your EF model than just the POCO classes - for example, the mapping fluent API - and the tool takes it into account.

[image]

Without further ado, it's the "EF Power Tools" VS extension (Beta 2 at the time of writing)

Read all about how to install and use it on the [related ADO.NET blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx)

Be warned, the diagram is read-only, but what would you expect when the input for it is your own code?