# Creating entity diagrams from code first classes

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I was just reading Asp.net MVC3 tutorials (Models (Data))

On this page [tutorial 4 of 10](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  on the ASP.NET website, it is shown that an entity diagram is created from code first classes. How to generate them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - Is there a way to create a model diagram from POCO classes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925684/entity-framework-code-first-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-model-diagram-from-poco)

Comment: @ladislav: yes , but that answer didnt solved my problem, its just one line answer and iam unable to figure out, how to do that

Comment: There IS a tool that creates a diagram from exactly the Entity Data Model generated by EF from your Code-First classes and relationships - see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12223054/11545. Reversing the database *might* work, but not necessarily with any database; plus, you'll get the database column names for properties, which aren't necessarily the same as your model's properties' names.

Comment: Also possible duplicate if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658078/how-do-you-create-a-visual-model-of-entityframework-code-first. I really like Slauma's answer, very simple and effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your schema has been created from the Code First classes you can reverse the db into a an edmx to visualise the Model.  Any classes generated from this obviously won't be related to your Code First classes though.

Comment: yes i did that, but i dont think that's the actual way to do.

Comment: @Praveen: There is no correct way to do that. EDMX cannot be created from code-first model (unless you write tool which will be able to do that).

Comment: That is the way the diagram was created for the tutorial (using the Database First designer on the database created by Code First).  There isn't yet a way to directly create a diagram from code written for Code First.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done very easily by using the **Class Diagram**. Add New Item > Class Diagram. Then drag and drop your code first classes into the diagram from the solution explorer.

Comment: be careful, some of the operation ,e.g. delete code will have a real effect on your classes

Answer (score 4):

A Class Diagram is OK, but it doesn't automatically show the relationships between classes. The slickest way that I have used is [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d/). Their description of the tool:

> When right-clicking on a C# project, the following context menu function is supported: 1) Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.

Comment: If you just want a simple, read-only view, right-click on your class inheriting from DbContext and select **Entity Framework » View Entity Date Model (Read-Only)**

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your project.  Open the copy and add a new item/ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  Edit the diagram for layout and print to a .pdf file.  Delete the copy of the project.

Anytime you make a change you will have to re-create the diagram and edit the layout, but I can usually get through the whole process in about 15 minutes.