# Missing ADO.NET Entity Data Model designer in Visual Studio 2012 Update 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am missing the ADO.NET Entity Data Model designer surface in my Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 installation (64 bit). I have tried every suggestions I have came across on Google search and several from stack overflow, but does not seem to fix the problem. I have uninstalled/re-installed Visual Studio numerous times but to no avail. I also installed EFTools6.1.3ForVS2012.

When I pick ADO.NET Entity Data Model from the Add New Item screen, the default name comes up as Model1 (without .edmx extension). The rest of the steps on the Entity Data Model Wizard works just fine, but after I pick the database objects and hit 'Finish' I get whole bunch of POCO classes but no Model1.edmx file.

I have exhausted all possible approaches to this problem. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshots can be found here: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=43E4FAB9B8B71426&resid=43E4FAB9B8B71426%211306&app=Word

Comment: Your screenshots show a selection of 'Code First' which does not automatically generate an edmx file.  When I use Code First I never end up generating or using an edmx file.  But it seems like it is possible to do what you want to do.  Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658078/how-do-you-create-a-visual-model-of-entityframework-code-first

Comment: @DavidTansey, thank you. This is helpful. I inherited few VS2012 projects projects, and they apparently uses "code first from database" approach and has the designer surface. Not particularly sure if the developer used different tool. Check this link: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?cid=43E4FAB9B8B71426&resid=43E4FAB9B8B71426%211309&app=Word

Comment: They probably installed the Power Tools.  Most important thing to keep in mind is that that EDMX generation is on-demand with Code First / Power Tools.  IOW the EDMX model will not necessarily reflect latest changes unless it has been regenerated with those changes.  This can be confusing because it does not behave that way when you are dealing with DB First or Model first.