# Is there any way to show all the model relations in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making support to an app developed in ASP.NET. Now we are finishing some views, but is there a problem with a model, and there is no information about the relations or others. Is there any way to show the relations of it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: that was `edmx` use.. assuming you're on code first, you can use a tools as suggested [in this QA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18665425/4648586).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add edxm file and add your tables to it will make a visual drawing for your table and relations between them