# How to generate such relationship diagram?

Tags: database, relationship

[image]

Hi guys, I know it's a simple question.

How can I generate such kind of database relationship diagram?

This will helps me a lot in my application design.

with 1 to n, n to n, 1 to 0 or 1 relationships explicitly on.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you... tried searching for it?  This is not a programming question.

Comment: I do believe this to be a programming question. Data structures regardless of where they are stored is a central to programming and are often the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are several tools that would let you diagram DB relationships. [This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30474/422353) and google can give you more examples.
2. That particular image is more than a diagram. It's a picture of an Object-Relational Mapping using EntityFramework with Visual Studio (2010 or newer I guess).

Comment: yes, you're right. I've been trying to generate a graph like this for my entity models but I can't find out how to do it.

Comment: Are you using (or trying to use) Entity Framework? If that's the case then your question should have been much more explicite.

Comment: In that case, is your problem something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4925684/422353

Answer (score -1):

For your many to many relationships you use a join table.

InstructorCourses { InstructorId (FK Instructor:InstructorId), CourseId (FK Course:CourseId) }